# Error when trying to bind viewpager and tablayout

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-databinding, android-tablayout

It's my first time I'm trying to use data binding and mvvm.
I want to implement ViewPager with TabLayout on my app in main activity.
I have 3 Fragments that will contain some details.
I'm trying to use data binding with MVVM, but when I run my app , i have error:

```
D:\Project files\movieswishlist\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out\com\enjoyapps\movieswishlist\DataBinderMapperImpl.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import com.enjoyapps.movieswishlist.databinding.ActivityMainBindingImpl;
                                               ^
  symbol:   class ActivityMainBindingImpl
  location: package com.enjoyapps.movieswishlist.databinding
```

Here is my Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        activityMainBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        activityMainBinding.setHandler(this);
        activityMainBinding.setPager(this);
        activityMainBinding.setManager(getSupportFragmentManager());

    }

    @BindingAdapter({"bind:handler"})
    public static void bindViewPagerAdapter(final ViewPager view, final MainActivity activity) {
        final TabAdapters adapter = new TabAdapters(view.getContext(), activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @BindingAdapter({"bind:pager"})
    public static void bindViewPagerTabs(final TabLayout view, final ViewPager pagerView) {
        view.setupWithViewPager(pagerView, true);
    }

}
```

And my TabsAdapter

```
public class TabAdapters extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private static final int POPULAR = 0;
    private static final int TOP_RATED = 1;
    private static final int UP_COMING = 2;

    private static final int[] TABS = new int[]{POPULAR, UP_COMING};

    private Context mContext;

    public TabAdapters(final Context context, final FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (TABS[position]) {
            case POPULAR:
                return new PopularMoviesFragment();
            case TOP_RATED:
                return new TopRatedMoviesFragment();
            case UP_COMING:
                return new UpComingMoviesFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TABS.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (TABS[position]) {
            case POPULAR:
                return "POPULAR";
            case TOP_RATED:
                return "TOP RATED";
            case UP_COMING:
                return "UP COMING";
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

And xml of mainactivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View"/>

        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="com.enjoyapps.movieswishlist.view.activities.MainActivity" />

        <variable
            name="pager"
            type="com.enjoyapps.movieswishlist.view.activities.MainActivity" />

        <variable
            name="manager"
            type="androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".view.activities.MainActivity">


        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            bind:handler="@{handler}"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="fixed">

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            bind:handler="@{pager}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```